# pyqt - Change widget text from other .py file

Tags: python, pyqt

I have two python files, the first one is to handle database related stuff and the second one imports that file so I can use it with PyQt.

The problem is if I want to change the label in the first file it doesn't work the application just crashes.

The reason I want the first file to be able to change the label is if an error occurs when trying to connect to the DB.

Here is a short view of my code:

First file.

```
from mysql.connector import (connection)
from datetime import *
from RPI1_ui import Ui_Form

'''Handling of database related stuff'''


class DatabaseUtility(Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self):
        #DB Connection
        self.cnx = None
        self.cursor = None

    def mysql_connect(self):
        # Database connection
        try:
            self.cnx = connection.MySQLConnection(user='root', password='', host='127.0.0.1', database='spicadb')
            self.cursor = self.cnx.cursor()
        except connection.errors.InterfaceError as e:
            self.lblShowInfo.setText(str(e))  # -> Try to change label

    def get_table(self):
        return self.run_command("SELECT * FROM tblseal")

    def get_columns(self):
        return self.run_command("SHOW COLUMNS FROM tblseal")
```

Second file.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QDialog
from datetime import *
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import os
import sys
import DatabaseHandling

'''Convert UI file to Python'''
os.chdir("C:\\Users\Gianni Declercq\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts")
os.system("pyuic5.exe H:\QtProjects\\RPI1.ui -o H:\QtProjects\\RPI1_ui.py")

from RPI1_ui import Ui_Form  # import after recreation of py file
from RPI1_Sec import SecondWindow

'''Main program'''


class MainWindow(QWidget, Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        #  Initialize variables
        self.dbu = DatabaseHandling.DatabaseUtility()
        self.spica_reference = None
        self.barcode = None
        self.msl = None
        self.package_body = None

        self.window2 = None

        # Get UI elements + resize window
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.resize(800, 480)

        # Define what should happen on button click
        self.btnQuit.clicked.connect(lambda: app.exit())
        self.btnInsert.clicked.connect(lambda: self.get_entry())
        self.btnTable.clicked.connect(lambda: self.new_window())

        # Style buttons
        self.btnQuit.setStyleSheet("background-color: red")
        self.btnInsert.setStyleSheet("background-color: green")
        self.btnTable.setStyleSheet("background-color: orange")

    def get_entry(self):
        try:
            self.spica_reference = self.txtReferentie.text()
            self.barcode = self.txtBarcode.text()
            self.msl = self.txtMsl.text()
            self.package_body = float(self.txtBodyPackage.text())

        except ValueError:
            self.lblShowInfo.setText("Please insert the correct values")
            self.lblShowInfo.setStyleSheet('color: red')
        else:
            self.dbu.mysql_connect()
            if self.dbu.cursor and self.dbu.cnx is not None:
                self.dbu.add_entry(self.spica_reference, self.barcode, self.msl, self.package_body, self.calc_floor_life)
```

Answer (score 0):

Give a "hook function" to the DatabaseUtility when initializing.

```
class MainWindow(QWidget, Ui_Form):
  def __init__():
    def ch_lab(text):
      self.lblShowInfo.setText(text)
    self.dbu = DatabaseHandling.DatabaseUtility(ch_lab)
class DatabaseUtility(Ui_Form):
  def __init__(cb):
    self.error_warn = cb
  #.. error happening
    self.error_warn('error')
```